# How to fix list style not showing when using CSS3 columns on Webkit

Tags: html, css, html-lists, multiple-columns

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/R7GUZ/3/

I'm having a heck of a time getting `list-style` to work in webkit for a parent OL styled with

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
```

How do I format an ordered list into columns with css3 and still maintain the `list-style` styling?

```
           <ol class="text-col2">
                <li>
                    <strong>Can we call you?</strong>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia.</p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <strong>Can we call you?</strong>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia.</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
```

​

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding 20px margin-left to the `li`s did the trick

```
ol li {
   list-style: decimal;
   margin-left: 20px
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this issue was driving me crazy until I figured it was a column v list-style-image problem. Your solution works, although I also removed  padding-left from the ol/ul element so that I didn't unnecessary extra spacing.

Answer (score 8):

It seems the numbers are actually hidden. This can be resolved by using the following property:

```
OL {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Note if you have reset the `margin` and `padding` properties (like in your example on jsFiddle where CSS have been *normalized*), you will have to set them to the right values so columns are correctly formatted.